# Access to a "GeoPoint" out of the method "run()"

Tags: android

I need to access the value "pt" of method "run ()" out of this method. How I can do it?. Here's the method:

```
public void minimaDistancia(final ItemizedOverlay itemized)
    {
        final MyLocationOverlay myloc = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapa);
        myloc.enableMyLocation(); //Activamos actualización de la posición
        myloc.enableCompass(); //Activamos la brújula
        myloc.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GeoPoint pt = myloc.getMyLocation();
            }
        });
     ...
    }
```

Thanks.

---

I need to access to the "min_dist" in this method:

```
public void processLocation(GeoPoint punto,ItemizedOverlay itemized)
    {
        double min_dist = 1000;
        double dist_aux;
        int i;

        Location puntoA = new Location("Punto 1");
        puntoA.setLatitude(punto.getLatitudeE6());
        puntoA.setLongitude(punto.getLongitudeE6());
        for(i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
            Location puntoB = new Location("Punto 2");
            puntoB.setLatitude(itemized.getItem(i).getPoint().getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
            puntoB.setLongitude(itemized.getItem(i).getPoint().getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
            dist_aux = puntoA.distanceTo(puntoB)/1000;
            dist_aux = (double)Math.round(dist_aux*100)/100;
            if(dist_aux < min_dist)
                min_dist = dist_aux;
        }
        minimun_distance = min_dist;
    }
```

I want to get the minimun distance between my location and the nearest hospital (is a first aid application).
I've tried to declare a global variable like this: public static double minimun_distance, but when I want to change it's value, simply doesn't do it. It doesn't change the minumun_distance value in the assignment.
I forgot to say that when I try to show a Toast in this method, the app crashes whit a RunTimeError (I see it in the Eclipse Debugger).

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an instance method that does the actual processing:

```
public void minimaDistancia(final ItemizedOverlay itemized)
    {
        final MyLocationOverlay myloc = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapa);
        myloc.enableMyLocation(); //Activamos actualización de la posición
        myloc.enableCompass(); //Activamos la brújula
        myloc.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                processLocation(myloc.getMyLocation());
            }
        });
    }

public void processLocation(GeoPoint pt)
{
 ...
}
```

EDIT: try this instead. I'm guessing that the location hasn't been set for some reason.

```
myloc.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    android.location.Location lf = myloc.getLastFix();
                    processLocation(new GeoPoint((int)(lf.getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(lf.getLongitude()*1E6)));
                }
            });
```

Comment: I've tried it... but it doesn't work. It gives me a RuntimeException when I call the processLocation method. Any idea?

Comment: Include the exception in the question so we can see what it is doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I solve the problem with the RunTimeException. The problem now is this: I need to access to a double value returned by "processLocation" for showing it in a Toast. How can I do it? because run() method don't allow returning values.

Comment: Pass the double value to the `processLocation` function and show your Toast in there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking. Where are you putting the toast routine?
Maybe you can use a global variable at the activity class level?

Edit - sorry about that. Should have put this at the end...